# Javafx 2.0 when Applet Security prompt, How to Customize the Background of empty Applet area?

Tags: java, html, applet, javafx, javafx-2

I have a Javafx 2.0 Applet working well. This applet requires all security permissions. This applet has a Light Grey background (same color as html background page).

So my problem is: when Java security requests the user to allow the applet, the background of the unload-yet-applet is dark grey. When the user clicks on "Execute", the background becomes Light Grey as wanted. But this is because the applet is loaded.

I want this empty applet area to be Light Grey (as the background of the html page) when this Security warning pops up. Do you guys have an idea how to do this?

*I'm using a preloader with a full rectangle filled with Light Grey, but the preloader seems to be launched after Java security all permissions allowed by the user.*

Here the result to let you better understand:

[image]

**HTML file without the stylesheet css (same problem if I remove the css):**

```
<html><head>
<SCRIPT src="./web-files/dtjava.js"></SCRIPT>
<script>
    function javafxEmbed() {
        dtjava.embed(
            {
                url : 'Test.jnlp',
                placeholder : 'app-placeholder',
                width : 600,
                height : 400
            },
            {
                javafx : '2.0+'
            },
            {}
        );
    }
    dtjava.addOnloadCallback(javafxEmbed);
</script>
</head><body>
<h2>Test page for <b>TEST</b></h2>
  <center><div id='app-placeholder'></div></center>
</body></html>
```

And this is the **JNLP file**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0" xmlns:jfx="http://javafx.com" href="Test.jnlp">
  <information>
    <title>Test</title>
    <vendor>Test</vendor>
    <homepage href="http://www.test.com/"/>
    <description>I don't know where this appears</description>
    <description kind="short">And I don't know where this appears too</description>
    <icon href="icon.png"/>
    <icon kind="splash" href="icon.png"/>
    <offline-allowed/>
  </information>
  <resources os="Windows">
    <jfx:javafx-runtime version="2.0+" href="http://javadl.sun.com/webapps/download/GetFile/javafx-latest/windows-i586/javafx2.jnlp"/>
  </resources>
  <resources>
    <j2se version="1.6+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
    <jar href="lib/test-Preloader.jar" size="5096" download="progress" />
    <jar href="test.jar" size="246346" download="eager" />
  </resources>
<security>
  <all-permissions/>
</security>
  <applet-desc  width="600" height="400" main-class="com.javafx.main.NoJavaFXFallback"  name="Test" />
  <jfx:javafx-desc  width="600" height="400" main-class="testApp.IM"  name="Test"  preloader-class="test.preloader.im_Preloader">
  </jfx:javafx-desc>
  <update check="background"/>
</jnlp>
```

Comment: The JNLP is invalid.  Validate it with JaNeLA.  What is the content of `dtjava.js`?

Comment: I tried to validate it with JaNeLA, but I've got an ExecutionException.nullpointerexception when opening the jnlp file

Comment: What is the detail in the text based report?

Answer (score 1):

See the [Loading Screen](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/applet/applet_deployment.html#LOADING_SCREEN) section of the Applet Deployment guide.

> The new plug-in offers better customization of the image which is displayed before the applet is loaded. Animated GIFs are now supported as the target of the image parameter, as described in the [Special Attributes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/plugin/developer_guide/special_attributes.html) section of the old Java Plug-In Guide. Additionally, the following new parameters are now supported: ...

Comment: In JavaFX 2.0, the JNLP is quite different, so I've written this `    <fx:param name="boxbgcolor" value="#eeeeee"/>` in the JNLP file to pass the specified argument to set the background box color as the same as the html background page. But, doesn't work either. I still see the dark grey box as long as I don't click on "Execute".

Comment: What is the entire HTML used?  Edit it into the question and notify me in a comment.

Comment: it doesn't come from the HTML because the html is the default template generated by Netbeans. Moreover when I remove the css file, and it does the same. So it might come from the fxml or the css applied to the fxml file. I will check it out.
By the way `<fx:param name="boxbgcolor" value="#eeeeee"/>` has no effect. This might work only for Java applet.

Comment: *"it doesn't come from the HTML because the html is the default template generated by Netbeans"* LOL.  I developed a program called [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/).  It is for validating JNLP files and checking other aspects of a JWS based launch/deployment.  A large part of my motivation for creating JaNeLA was the rubbish JNLP files produced by ***Netbeans***.  So don't try & convince me with your assurances that Netbeans is capable of producing logical, valid **HTML.**  Further, when I ask for the detail of the HTML, I advise you to not waste my time by ***posting it***.

Comment: hey I am sorry. didn't wanted to be mean to you. I haven't try and convince you of any assurances. You talked about HTML file, not JNLP file. I put the HTML in the question.